# How to prove if $x \geq n$, $x^n \geq n!$ for all natural numbers $n$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

This is the [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nYyV.jpg)

Before this question, I had to prove that if $n > m, n! > m!$. I don't think that will be useful for this question.

if I were to use induction, could I use the base case n = 1
then assume that x^k > k!
then use that to prove x^(k+1) > (k+1)!?
but then I would need to show that x > k+1 (which I'm not sure how it would be done)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Hint: which $n$ positive quantities, each $\le x$, would you multiply to get $n!$?

Comment: $x \geq n \Rightarrow x^n \geq n^n = n . n . n \cdots n \geq n (n - 1) (n - 2) \cdots 1 = n!$

Comment: @Essaidi Of course, we should assume that $n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$, in order to disregard the indeterminate form $0^0$.

Comment: As commented by @Essaidi the key to the problem is consideration of the intermediate value $$n^n.$$

Comment: @Essaidi That should be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this :**
$$x ≥ n ≥ 1 $$
$$x ≥ n ≥ 2 $$
$$   . . .  $$
$$x ≥ n ≥ n $$

**By multiplying the ends of the inequality with each other**

$$x × x×..×x ≥ 1 × 2 ×...×n $$

$$x^n ≥ n! $$

**Which is required to be proven**

Answer (score 0):

If $x \geq n$, then $x^{n} \geq n^{n}$. But
$$
n^{n} = \underbrace{n \times n \times n \cdots n \times n}_{n \text{times}} \geq n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \cdots  \times 1 = n!
$$
Soon, we obtain
$$
x^{n} \geq n^{n}, \ \ \text{if} \ x \geq n, \ \ \text{with} \ n \neq 0.
$$